# PC just rebooted itself, failed to restart automatically now refuses to boot

Tags: hardware-failure, power, desktop-computer

I tried to restart automatically but it failed after about 2 secs. It won't switch on at all now. What part just failed? It's a desktop.

Comment: What *precisely* happens now when you try to boot it? How far do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be several things. I had similar problem to this with a Laptop and the Best Buy Geek Squad said it was power issue. The laptop collected dust for a few years then one day I take it appart and I figured I would try tightening the CPU, it worked after that. So it was CPU issue not a power supply issue, but both could be the case. Another thing it could be is cooling. As safety feature computers will sometimes shut themselves down if they are over heating. If your fans aren't running then this to could be the cause.